# Save log files and transfer to PC

Tags: iphone, macos, file, transfer

In my iPhone application, there is a requirement to save a few log files in the phone(files are run-time generated). 
Then I have to copy/transfer the files into the pc. 
Can anyone suggest the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to log files in ../Documents (one directory up from the .app where the executable resides - I'm pretty sure this is the default working directory). Once you've saved them there, you can go in XCode to Window > Organizer. In there, select your iPhone/iPod, under Applications expand your app's name, and it should show "Application Data" - just click the little down arrow on the right side to download your app's data.